# Remove the repeating items and return the order number

Tags: c#, linq

I want to remove the repeating items of a list.I can realize it whit Distinct() easily.But i also need to get the order number of the items which have been removed.I can't find any function in linq to solve the problem and finally realize it with the following code:

```
    public List<string> Repeat(List<string> str)
    {
        var Dlist = str.Distinct();
        List<string> repeat = new List<string>();
        foreach (string aa in Dlist)
        {
            int num = 0;
            string re = "";
            for (int i = 1; i <= str.LongCount(); i++)
            {
                if (aa == str[i - 1])
                {
                    num = num + 1;
                    re = re + " - " + i;
                }
            }
            if (num > 1)
            {
                repeat.Add(re.Substring(3));
            }
        }
        return repeat;
    }
```

Is there any other way to solve the problem more simple? Or is there any function in linq I missed?Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query does exactly the same as your function, if I'm not mistaken:

```
var repeated = str.GroupBy(s => s).Where(group => group.Any())
    .Select(group =>
    {
        var indices = Enumerable.Range(1, str.Count).Where(i => str[i-1] == group.Key).ToList();
        return string.Join(" - ", group.Select((s, i) => indices[i]));
    });
```

It firstly groups the items of the original list, so that every item with the same content is in a group. Then it searches for all indices of the items in the group in the original list, so that we have all the indices of the original items of the group. Then it joins the indices to a string, so that the resulting format is similiar to the one you requested. You could also transform this statement lambda to an anonymous lambda:

```
var repeated = str.GroupBy(s => s).Where(group => group.Any())
    .Select(group => string.Join(" - ",
        group.Select((s, i) =>
            Enumerable.Range(1, str.Count).Where(i2 => str[i2 - 1] == group.Key).ToList()[i])));
```

However, this significantly reduces performance.

---

I tested this with the following code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var str = new List<string>
    {
        "bla",
        "bla",
        "baum",
        "baum",
        "nudel",
        "baum",
    };
    var copy = new List<string>(str);
    var repeated = str.GroupBy(s => s).Where(group => group.Any())
        .Select(group => string.Join(" - ",
            group.Select((s, i) =>
                Enumerable.Range(1, str.Count).Where(i2 => str[i2 - 1] == group.Key).ToList()[i])));
    var repeated2 = Repeat(str);
    var repeated3 = str.GroupBy(s => s).Where(group => group.Any())
        .Select(group =>
        {
            var indices = Enumerable.Range(1, str.Count).Where(i => str[i-1] == group.Key).ToList();
            return string.Join(" - ", group.Select((s, i) => indices[i]));
        });

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", repeated) + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", repeated2) + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", repeated3));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static List<string> Repeat(List<string> str)
{
    var distinctItems = str.Distinct();
    var repeat = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in distinctItems)
    {
        var added = false;
        var reItem = "";
        for (var index = 0; index < str.LongCount(); index++)
        {
            if (item != str[index]) 
                continue;
            added = true;
            reItem += " - " + (index + 1);
        }

        if (added)
            repeat.Add(reItem.Substring(3));
    }

    return repeat;
}
```

Which has the followin output:

```
1 - 2
3 - 4 - 6
5

1 - 2
3 - 4 - 6
5

1 - 2
3 - 4 - 6
5
```

Comment: thx，I learn a lot from your answer.But it seems each way to solve the problem is a little complex.I think maybe MS should add the function one day :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `repeat` method you can use following way to get repeated items

```
var repeated = str.GroupBy(s=>s)
      .Where(grp=>grp.Count()>1)
      .Select(y=>y.Key)
      .ToList();
```

Comment: Good. I would also change `Repeat(List<string> str)` to `GetDuplicates(List<string> items)`.

Comment: I didnt ask the question so I cannot mark it answered. I can only upvote

Comment: thx for your answer.It's a good way to get the repeated items. But like a previous answer.It could only get what contexts are repeated but not the order number of them.

Comment: You can get order number from “select” statement part.

Comment: could you tell me what I should do in detail.With your code ,after doing where(),it only leave occurrence number of repeated items and their value.whit select(y >= y.key),I can get the value but not order number.

Comment: check this to understand group by http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/group-by-with-linq1

Comment: it seems that after doing group by,the repeated items whill be put in a group.At the same time,they will lose their primary No. what I need.Did I get it wrong?